# Autofill service doesn't show up suggestions automatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, autofill

I only get autofill suggestions after I make long press on input field and select 'autofill'. As I've read in other answers, this forces `requestAutofill`. I've enabled my autofill service like so:

First, check if it's available and set autofill hints for input fields:

```
autoFillService = requireContext().getSystemService(AutofillManager::class.java)
autoFillService?.let { autoFillServiceEnabled = it.isEnabled }
Timber.d("Autofill service is $autoFillServiceEnabled as $autoFillService")
if (autoFillServiceEnabled && autoFillService?.isAutofillSupported == true) {
   setAutoFillHints()
}
```

Hints are set like this. I've also set `android:importantForAutofill="yes"` in xml:

```
firstNameEditText.setAutofillHints(HintConstants.AUTOFILL_HINT_PERSON_NAME_GIVEN)
```

Finally, I request autofill service on input field when `onFocus` event occurs:

```
autoFillService?.requestAutofill(fieldView)
```

Why it doesn't show autofill suggestions automatically? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same exact issue as you, but for an email autofill and I solved it in a pretty similar way to what you described:

I added this to my resource .xml file to the element I want auto filled:

```
android:autofillHints="emailAddress"
android:importantForAutofill="yes"
```

And then in my Fragment.kt:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val autofillManager = requireContext().getSystemService(AutofillManager::class.java)

        binding.emailEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus){
                autofillManager.requestAutofill(view)
            }
        }
    }
```

You did write that you

> Finally, I request autofill service on input field when onFocus event
> occurs:

But I'm not sure if we do it in the same place.

Of course it's possible that autofill differs for AUTOFILL_HINT_PERSON_NAME_GIVEN and AUTOFILL_HINT_EMAIL_ADDRESS or that you maybe use a different Autofill service (I used Google). But for me the solution I sent worked and now the email suggestion is always visible above the keyboard.